# catch port_close(Port) is not preventing exception being thrown

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I have a gen_server which wraps a port. The gen_server's `terminate/2` callback it calls `port_close(Port)` to ensure the port is closed. If the port has already been closed (which would cause the gen_server to stop), my understanding is this will throw a `bad_argument` exception. To deal with this, I use the expression `catch port_close(Port)`. However, you guessed it, the exception is still being thrown.

The code:

```
terminate(Reason, #state{port=Port}) ->
    lager:info("Terminating ~p due to ~p", [?MODULE, Reason]),
    catch port_close(Port).
```

And the exception:

```
6:31:03.034 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.69.0> with 1 neighbours exited with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:port_close(#Port<0.3906>) in my_gen_server:terminate/2 line 62 in gen_server:terminate/6 line 725
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  port_close/1
        called as port_close(#Port<0.3906>)
     in call from my_gen_server:terminate/2 (src/my_gen_server.erl, line 62)
     in call from gen_server:terminate/6 (gen_server.erl, line 722)
     in call from proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3 (proc_lib.erl, line 227)
```

The same error occurs whether `Reason = normal | term()`

I'd be very thankful for any advice as to why this is not being caught!

Comment: That should not happen with port_close. Have you made sure that you are running the code you think you are running (i.e. saved the file, comiled it, loaded it etc)? If you are sure could you provide a limited example of what you are doing where port_close badarg is not caught?

Comment: @Lukas - sorry for the delay, 'That should not happen' made me think I could figure it out, but no dice. It's definitely the code which I think is running - I can happily break it with syntax errors. I've included the actual code. Also, I tried wrapping the port_close with if is_port(Port), but unsurprisingly that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is I need a different return value, in this case `ok`.

```
terminate(Reason, #state{port=Port}) ->
    lager:info("Terminating ~p due to ~p", [?MODULE, Reason]),
    catch port_close(Port),
    ok.
```

I'm still a bit confused since the [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module%3aterminate-2) states for `terminate/2` that `The return value is ignored.`